# Global declarations are illegal in Verilog 2001 syntax!

Tags: syntax, global, verilog, modelsim

I have written something small in verilog:

```
`define LW 6'b100011

`define SW 6'b101011

parameter [3:0]
    i_fetch = 4'b0001,
    decode_rr = 4'b0010,
    mem_addr = 4'b0100,
    alu_exec = 4'b1000;
```

and i am getting this error: **Error: test.v(5): (vlog-2155) Global declarations are illegal in Verilog 2001 syntax.**

What I am doing wrong? I am using ModelSim XE III/Starter 6.4b - Custom Xilinx Version!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `parameter` statement has to be within a module:

```
module a_module ();

  parameter a_parameter = 4;

endmodule
```

In fact, most stuff in verilog has to be within a module block.